How to impute a value if value has only one occasion in a sequence
Basically, I want to interpolate, using R, when a value is different for only one occasion (in this case a month). Let's say my data looks like this:
    df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
      month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6), 
      status = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'))

How do I interpolate, within ids, when a status only occurs once within a sequence. In my example, I want to change the first b (row 3) into a, but none of the others need changing.

Is status binary or can there be, e.g., a third letter 'c'?

What should happen with a, a, b, a, b, a, b, b?

Status is not binary and a, a, b, a, b, b should become a, a, a, a, b, b

What is the expected result for c, a, b, c, a, b, c, b, a, a, a? You need to define clear rules.

@Roland that is fair. I guess the idea behind is that a single entry within a sequence could be an error or otherwise not relevant. So in your example the expected result would be the same as the input. I want to adapt a single value when they are surrounded by other values that are the same to each other: e.g. a,a,a,b,a,a,a -> a,a,a,a,a,a,a and a,b,c,d,c,a,b -> a,b,c,c,c,a,b

I am not sure if you want to play a sliding window to replace the "outlier" by its neighbors. If so, maybe the code below should fit your goal (assuming the sliding window moves from left to right)
f <- \(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  if (x[2]==x[3] && x[2]!=x[1]) {
    x[1] <- x[2]
  }
  if (x[l-1]==x[l-2] && x[l-1]!=x[l]) {
    x[l] <- x[l-1]
  }
  for (i in 2:(length(x) - 1)) {
    if (x[i + 1] == x[i - 1] && x[i] != x[i + 1]) {
      x[i] <- x[i + 1]
    }
  }
  x
}

then you will obtain
> f(c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b"))
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b"

> f(c("a", "b", "b"))
[1] "b" "b" "b"

> f(c("b", "b", "a"))
[1] "b" "b" "b"

> f(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "c", "a", "b"))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "b"


What if there is a leading or trailing single element? E.g. a, b, b, b or b, b, b, a

That looks great, thank you. How are leading or trailing elements treated (as mentioned by Darren Tsai). To do it within ids I guess I can nest this is another for loop?

@DarrenTsai aha, thanks for the interesting example. I updated my solution and hope it could deal with the edge cases well too.

@business_of_ferrets you can take a look at my update

Performance will be better if you handle the second and third if outside of the loop.

@Roland yes, that makes sense, thanks for your advice!

Oh please don’t abuse the anonymous function syntax to define named functions. It makes the code harder to read. The entire point of \() is to be innocuous in nested expressions. But we don’t want named function definitions to be innocuous, on the contrary!
